# Open a huge size image(about 1.5GB) in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I use imread to read an image (about 1.5GB), but the image.data[x] value always be 0.

Is there any parameters I can use?

Or,is there any other API that I can use to load this image.

Thanks

ubuntu 12.04

Image information : 
XXX.tif

1.21GB

Dimensions : 34795 * 37552

Horizontal resolution : 150 dpi

Vertical resolution : 150 dpi

bit depth : 8

Comment: Are you compiling for x64?

Comment: also there are size limitations, since width and height have to fit into a (signed) int

Comment: What format is the image? 1.5GB is the compressed or the raw size? Have you checked that your code works ok with small images?

Comment: @RowlandShaw Yes, it's for x64

Comment: @leonbloy It's a .tif file . And it's ok with small image (about 50MB)

Comment: The only practical solution - on Linux, is to use ImageMagick to split the images prior to processing by OpenCV. Aside from splitting, you can also try scaling it down, cropping, or anything that helps to bring down the file size. I develop custom solutions for large images (commercially), so consider yourself very lucky that you have access to a tool as great as ImageMagick for free.

Comment: Also see: https://github.com/ilya-lavrenov/opencv/commit/5db1754d499d21b9dda4a6ad36f98c22db97b994

Answer (score 1):

The cv::Mat is a continuous memory space allocation. It might be almost impossible to allocate 1.5GB of continuous memory space. Try splitting the file either spatially or based on its different channels.